# MacOS: NSDraggingItem as both fileURL and data

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

My app shows a list of files (images, videos, audios, texts), similar to Finder.

I use LazyVGrid, instead of List or Table views, because I want to render a grid, not just rows.

I want to enable dragging items from my app to other apps. Some other apps (e.g. Finder) require fileURL in the drop item provider, while others require data e.g. image (afaik e.g. Figma).

I want to make it possible to drag multiple items at a time, which afaik SwiftUI's `onDrag` doesn't support yet (the callback has to return exactly one `NSItemProvider`) unless it's a List or Table view.
So I use an `NSHostingView`:

```swift
class MultiDragNSHostingView<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content: View {
    let fileURL: URL
    let selectedFileURLs: [URL]

    // ...

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        beginDraggingSession(with: [selectedFileURLs.map { url in getDraggingItem(for: url) }], event: event, source: self)
        super.mouseDragged(with: event)
    }

    private func getDraggingItem(for url: URL) -> NSDraggingItem {
        // ???
    }
}
```

If I used `onDrag { NSItemProvider(contentsOf: fileURL) }`, then for a PNG image, the drop item provider would contain these `registeredTypeIdentifiers`: `["public.png", "public.file-url"]`.

**My question is: How should I implement `getDraggingItem` above, to get drop item providers similar to when using `onDrag`, i.e. having both "public.file-url" and "public.png" (or other image/video/audio/text) registered type identifiers?**

I checked the initializer for `NSDraggingItem`, it has one param `pasteboardWriter: NSPasteboardWriting`. Conforming types are e.g. `NSFilePromiseProvider` and `NSImage`, but I don't see yet what pasteboardWriter I need to answer my question above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple item providers in your case because NSItemProvider can contain multiple representations of an item.  Create an instance of NSItemProvider then call registerDataRepresentation for each type you want to register.